# Display Image in jsp page

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I am displaying an image on jsp page whose path is stored in database. I'm retrieving image using `<img src="<%=rs.getString(2)%>">` but it is not showing in browser while if running on eclipse it is shown properly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please correct your question. You seem missing some text

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: did u try adding the path of the image in src of this image tag directly ? also what you getting in rs.getString print it

Comment: go to the developer tool and check whether the path where the image is being searched is correct..

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can check is that you are providing proper path for your *img* tag
i.e.:

```
<img src="images/myProject/<%=rs.getString(2)%>">
```

But one thing that JSP is not meant to do is to cause Java code to be executed on client browser and hence the use of scriplet tags has reduced to negligible.
Since the use of *scriplet tags* in JSPs has been obsolete, you should prefer to use JSTL tags instead. Following code snippet can be helpful:

**JSP file:**

Include tag library first:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Then in *img* tag you can direct point to the servlet that can stream the image on the browser.

```
<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath }/yourServlet?param_name=$[pass_any_Parameter_value]" />
```

**Servlet file:**

```
 if (rs.next()) {
        response.getOutputStream().write(rs.getBytes(2));
    }
```